# Properly evaluate placeholders in materialised view from JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot

Here is my case:
I have the following sql file (my_view.sql - containing the definition of a materialised view, Oracle dialect) returning all the products having expire_date > sysdate:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
 AS
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE expire_date > sysdate
```

Now in the application code I have a Spring Service using this view:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Value("${expire_date}")
  private String expireDate;// property will be injected at runtime by Spring, but how to pass this string to be evaluated in the sql script through jdbcTemplate

  public MyService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
     this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  public void callMaterialisedView() {
    try (Connection zs1DbConnection = 
      jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
       jdbcTemplate.execute("BEGIN dbms_mview.refresh('my_view', 'c');END;");
    }
  }
}
```

My question: Is it possible to make **expire_date** configurable and pass it from the application code as a placeholder to the sql script?

Making it configurable is easy - i can use Spring @Value annotation to inject a concrete value to my application code. What I miss is how (if possible at all) to pass this value from **jdbcTemplate** to the script to be evaluated properly.

In the final variant, I imagine the script to look like (**expire_date** being passed from **jdbcTempalte**):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
 AS
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE expire_date > to_date(${expire_date})
```

Answer (score 2):

The materialized view does not accept a parameter, but you can create a dummy table with one column and insert/update your parameter value in table.

It's an alternative solution.

In MV SQL you can write something like " `where expire_date > (select dt_col from dummy_tab)` " as below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
 AS
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE expire_date > (select dt_col from dummy_tab);
```

Comment: So, before refreshing the MV you have to update the table values